# Counterexamples to the definable (P,Q)-Theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, model-theory

Pierre Simon conjectured a model-theoretic definable version of Matoušek’s (p,q) -theorem in NIP theories:

[Conjecture 5.1]: Let T be NIP and M⊨T . Let ϕ(x;d) ∈ L(U) a formula, non-forking over M . Then there is θ(y) ∈ tp(d/M) such that the partial type {ϕ(x;d′): d′ ∈ θ(U)} is consistent.

'Invariant types in NIP theories' (2015)

It seems Itay Kaplan has recently solved this conjecture with 'A definable (p,q) -theorem for NIP theories'(2022).

I believe this proof can potentially be generalized to the case where only ϕ(x,y) has NIP with some minor restrictions since Itay's proof only relies implicitly on T having NIP in a couple of places. Does anyone know of any counterexamples to the definable (P,Q)-theorem in classes outside NIP (e.g. in NTP2)?

Comment: Are you asking for a counterexample where $\phi(x,y)$ is NIP? For arbitrary formulas, a good counterexample is $xEa \wedge \neg xEb$ in the random graph.

Comment: Thanks for the response. NIP is ideal but I'm interested in any example